# rpm i386 patch did not recognize dependency patch with x86_64

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I have an rpm patch "test_patch2-c-102.rpm"(i386) this patch Requires "test_patch-101-b.rpm"(x86_64).

We specified the requires like this.
Requires: test_patch = 101

In my target  "test_patch-101-b.rpm"(x86_64) is already installed. However when try to install the patch "test_patch2-c-102.rpm"(i386) it does not recognize the 
"test_patch-101-1.rpm"(x86_64).

### Below is the error message:

error: Failed dependencies:
        test_patch = 101 is needed by test_patch2-c-102.i386

Please help me to fix this issue

Comment: I'm not positive, but I think you'll have to _explicitly_ have a "`Provides`" tag to cross architectures. See ["Creating Virtual Capabilities"](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora_Draft_Documentation/0.1/html/RPM_Guide/ch-advanced-packaging.html).

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be adding a require on a package file name like

```
Requires: test_patch-101-1.rpm
```

Try writing the dependency on the package name/version/release (not the file name)

```
Requires: test_patch = 101-1
```

Change the comparison to taste ( like

```
Requires: test_patch >= 101
```

Comment: You also seem to want cross-platform (i386 <-> x86_64) dependencies. That is fairly tricky to accomplish, but there are several ways to do. The best solution is to avoid cross-platform dependencies if at all possible.

Comment: Thank you.  I have tried tried both ways. When i give "Requires: test_patch = 101-b" it still did not recognize the patch. Then i tried to give the "Requires: test_patch >= 101. This way it is working. However if i give any number it is still working after >= . Suppose I tested by giving "Requires: test_patch >= 120" this one also working, which should not work as i have patch with version 101.

Comment: The comparison uses a triple of {E,V,R} == Epoch/Version/Release compared in that preced3ence order. A value that isn't specified will match any/all values. The likely explanation of Requires: test_patch >= 120 matching is that you have multiple instances, and the match was on another instance than the one you were expecting.